# Is it possible to mock API calls with Jest in NodeJS without jest.mock('module')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

My NodeJS application has to do some API requests, so I'm mocking their return as my tests are just for my application's business logic. However, there's two things that I quite didn't understand.

I'm using jest's mockImplementation method to change the return of my service, but I can't make it work without calling jest.mock with the service beforehand.

Also, if I try to set automock: true in my jest.config.js, it returns me an error:|

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'gracefulify' of undefined`

Here's my test.js code in where I'm testing a function that calls automation.js, which has my application logic and make the calls for my services:

```
const automation = require('../automations/fake.automation');

// MOCKS
const mockedBlingProduct = require('../mocks/bling-product.mocks.json');
const mockedShopifyCreatedProduct = require('../mocks/shopify-created-product.mocks.json');

// SERVICES
const BlingProductService = require('../services/bling-product.service');
const ShopifyProductService = require('../services/shopify-product.service');

jest.mock('../services/bling-product.service');
jest.mock('../services/shopify-product.service');

describe('Automation test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const blingMockedReturn = jest.fn(() => {
      return mockedBlingProduct;
    });

    const shopifyMockedReturn = jest.fn(() => {
      return mockedShopifyCreatedProduct;
    });

    BlingProductService.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        list: blingMockedReturn
      };
    });

    ShopifyProductService.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        create: shopifyMockedReturn
      };
    });
  });

  it('should return status SUCCESS', async () => {
    const result = await 
.run();
    expect(result).toEqual({ status: 'SUCCESS' });
  });
});
```

And here's the code of one of my services, keep in mind that the logic behind the API calls is abstracted from the service. In the mockImplementation I'm trying to overwrite the list and create functions inside them:

```
class BlingPriceService {
  async list(query = {}) {
    const httpMethod = 'GET';
    const resource = 'produtos/page={pageNumber}/json';

    const options = {
      queryString: query,
      urlParams: {
        pageNumber: 1,
      }
    };

    return blingComponent.request(httpMethod, resource, options);
  }
}

module.exports = BlingPriceService;
```

Comment: Are your services (`BlingProductService`, `ShopifyProductService`) functions or modules? `mockImplementation` is to be used for overriding functions while `jest.mock` operates on modules.

Comment: They are modules.
I'm using mockImplementation to override the list and create functions inside them, isn't that correct?

Comment: Then I guess they have some functions for retrieving data? In which case you would do: `BlingProductService.yourFunctionForRetreivingData.mockResolvedValue(mockedBlingProduct);`

Comment: I've update the question with my service code if you want to give it a look.
Should I keep the jest.mock if I'm going to use function.mockresolvedValue?

Comment: @Christian Just tried changing the test to use mockResolvedValue but now the mock isn't working, the service is working as if the mock just doesn't exist and therefore is calling the api, is there something wrong with the way I did it?

('Automation test', () => {
  it('should return status SUCCESS', async () => {
    const bling = new BlingProductService();
    bling.list.mockResolvedValue(mockedBlingProduct);

    const result = await automation.run();
    expect(result).toEqual({ status: 'SUCCESS' });
  });
});

Comment: Yes, the problem is that your creating a new instance of your BlingProductService class and thereby overwrites the mocked functions with the original ones. I suggest you use spies instead (see answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const automation = require('../automations/fake.automation');

// MOCKS
const mockedBlingProduct = require('../mocks/bling-product.mocks.json');
const mockedShopifyCreatedProduct = require('../mocks/shopify-created-product.mocks.json');

// SERVICES
const BlingProductService = require('../services/bling-product.service');
const ShopifyProductService = require('../services/shopify-product.service');

describe('Automation test', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(BlingProductService.prototype, 'list').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockedBlingProduct));

    jest.spyOn(ShopifyProductService.prototype, 'list').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockedShopifyCreatedProduct));
  });

  afterAll(() => {
     jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should return status SUCCESS', async () => {
    const result = await automation.run();
    expect(result).toEqual({ status: 'SUCCESS' });
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly fine, thanks! Is it fine to assume that jest.spyOn is doing the same job that jest.mock was on the code I used on the question and therefore is not necessary in this case?

Comment: Yes, `jest.mock´ is auto-mocking the whole module while `spyOn` lets you "spy" and/or mock individual methods. Actually if you want to use `jest.mock` on a class you can follow this example: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementationdocsenmock-function-apimockfnmockimplementationfn-or-mockimplementationoncedocsenmock-function-apimockfnmockimplementationoncefn